# Animated Shape Key on a Rigid Body : The shape change is ignored by the physics simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, shape-keys

I need to animate the shape of an Rigid Body object with shape key.

The problem is that the Shape Key animation is ignored and only the initial Shape is taken into account in the Rigid Body animation.

It is well detailed here :
[Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cc7cpwiYqGc)

Here the ball is getting bigger but is still acting as if it was small ( same as me when I gain weight ).

[image: Ball getting bigger]

Here is my **Blender 3.6** file:
[image]

( The clean version, without the problems mentionned by Gordon in the comments )

Sorry ... but I suspect that I have missed something obvious here.

Thanks !

Comment: i think this might be a bug

Comment: Thanks Chris. Worst case scenario. Is so, the question is : since which version ?

Comment: @Nicolas Sorry, we are not keeping track of all functions in each Blender version. In general the _Rigid Body_ physics are a bit buggy sometimes. If I build something like shown in the video, it can work. Playing with a few parameters might result in weird unpredictable behavior though. But, in your file I found a few things that surely will not help: you haven't applied the scale on the objects, this can lead to issues. There are drivers on the scale of the sphere which is problematic and different from the tutorial. Then your objects are huge. Also bounciness is buggy with deforming.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you are absolutely right.  I applyed the scale and removed the (useless) driver. The problem is still here. ( Sorry I should haved delivered a "clean" file. ) I am going to try this on my older versions.

Comment: I have tryied with older Blender versions up to 2.81.
The problem is still here.

Comment: this time you didn't apply the rotation. if you apply it, it works. Looks like scaling your object during animation was the problem, changing shape keys seems to works (at least in my tests)

Comment: @Chris, I don't get It. I applyed the ball's rotation, but , no change. 'Looks like scaling your object during animation was the problem ' but what is scaled ? Sorry ...

Comment: i didn't mean the ball, but the passive part below it. You scaled the ball in the first version of the blend file, which you deleted now. I rebuild your setup in a clean small way, and with shape keys it works fine, as soon as i keyframed the scale, it didn't work anymore.

Comment: Well, I rebuilt the setup ... and it works.  But I don't see ( yet ) what made the other version fail. I go for a little inquiry, replacing the elements one by one ...
( ending this post without a proper answer would be embarassing ... )

Comment: Well as Chris said, rebuilding the setup in a simple and clean way provided a working example. 
By comparison,I found that setting a low sensitivity margin for the ball ( 0.001 ) could lead to the same simulation fail.
Sadly, if I set the default value ( 0.05 ) in the failing example I provided ( for the ball and the floor ), I can't get to make it work. So this sensitivity margin value cannot be identified as the sole cause of this problem.